# How to remove file system contributor in GitHub?

Tags: git, github

When I create the project with predefined file structure like **Android**, **VueJs** or **AngularJS** project and push the project in GitHub, the project comes with a second unknown contributor with the name [Jar64](https://github.com/jar64)
[image]

Example: In this [android project](https://github.com/elirehema/BaseAndroidPro/graphs/contributors), and in this [VueJs Project](https://github.com/elirehema/VueJS/graphs/contributors) in the contributor section I can find two contributors who are me and Jar64.

[image]

How can I remove or avoid this contributor?

Comment: Looks like Jar64 is an actual user on GtHub and he/she/it has made commits on your repo. But from the email ID (elirehema@..) I think it's you but committing from a different PC (anyway a diff `git config`). It's a valid user. Try `git log` and figure out who made those commits (might be you, so figure out from were you made those commits.)

Comment: Also, what does "with a predefined structure" mean? If you're starting by cloning an existing repo those commits will necessarily be part of your project. Their authors will (rightly, I think) show up as contributors.

Comment: @Chris predefined structure is the project wich come with their own file structure like android project, AngularJs etc. Other projects can be created manualy like java projects.

Comment: @clmno  i have tried to check my git log and shared it [HERE](https://gist.github.com/elirehema/6c0c0db35b935a53015a365642129c37) But jar64 keep on working on my repo as shown [here](https://github.com/elirehema/BaseAndroidPro/pulse). He is commiting, approving, merging etc

Comment: @eLi You can remove the permission you've given to this user, read [this](https://help.github.com/en/articles/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository) Remove the user so he/she/it can't commit into your repo it will need to `pull a request`.

Comment: @eLi, are [the commits associated with the other account](https://github.com/elirehema/BaseAndroidPro/commits/master) ones you've actually made yourself?

Comment: @Chris all the commits i have created my and commit it by myself

Comment: Then clmno is right: one of your tools (the `git` CLI itself, or a graphical Git tool, or your editor if you commit there, etc.) is configured to use an email address that `jar64` has registered with GitHub. That probably means you've set up an email address that you don't actually own. See https://help.github.com/en/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user